# python polyfit error due to decimals

Tags: python

I have a couple of Python lists (lets say 'x' and 'y'), in which the numbers are all 'Decimals', using the 'decimal' module. I need this because the numbers are precise to many decimal places.

I then need to take the gradient of a plot of y versus x using

```
slope,intercept = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

I assume that the polyfit doesn't like me using decimals in this way? Is there any way around it?

Thank you!

Comment: It doesnt make sense to use the decimal module in this context, switch to floats

Comment: but floats don't have enough decimal places for the precision I need...

Comment: Joining @fraxel in suggesting floats, since the result is a parameter estimate with surely enough uncertainty.

Comment: ... but implementing your own *linear* fitting procedure with decimals won't be difficult either.

Comment: using floats, all my y values would be identical, and the gradient would be 0. using decimal values, the gradient will be slight but greater than 0. I will look into making my own fitting procedure though, thank you.

Comment: if all the numbers have the same value for the first 10 decimal places (or whatever), all you need to do is rescale your data. ie. 2.3453453453457 and 2.3453453453459 become 7 and 9 etc. Thats the easy way to solve the problem.